# I can't figure out what's wrong, getting a 'type already defined error'

Tags: java, types

Ok so, I'm learning java using a book I bought online, and for some reason Java wont allow this program to work even though it's the exact text from the book. Can someone explain why I keep getting told 'The type SimpleCircle is already defined'? it shows this as an error next to the line "SimpleCircle() { radius = 1; }"

```
public class SimpleCircle {
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a circle with radius 1
        SimpleCircle circle1 = new SimpleCircle();
        System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius " 
                + circle1.radius + " is " + circle1.getArea());

        //create a a circle with radius 25
        SimpleCircle circle2 = new SimpleCircle(25);
        System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius " 
                + circle2.radius + " is " + circle2.getArea());

        //create a circle with radius 125
        SimpleCircle circle3 = new SimpleCircle(125);
        System.out.println("the area of the circle of radius " 
                + circle3.radius + " is " + circle3.getArea());

        //modify circle radius
        circle2.radius = 100;
        System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius " 
                + circle2.radius + " is " + circle2.getArea());
    }

    double radius;

    /** construct a circle with radius 1 */
    SimpleCircle() {
        radius = 1;
    }

    /** construct a circle with a specified radius */
    SimpleCircle(double newRadius) {
        radius = newRadius;
    }

    // return the area of this circle
    double getArea() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    // return the perimeter of the circle
    double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    // set a new radius for this circle
    void setRadius(double newRadius) {
        radius = newRadius;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted works fine. Are you sure you don't have two copies of the source file? How are you compiling your code? Are you using an IDE, and if so, which?

Comment: The code is working fine.

Comment: Ah, wait, I'm using Eclipse and I do have another file using the same class. I never thought about that. EDIT: Tested it, yep, it was a class from another file conflicting. Thanks, this kind of stuff helps.

Answer (score -1):

I too faced the same error.The reason for this is the folder in which you are working is contained with another file(other than the present working file) in which the same class(here SimpleCircle) was used.Simply modify the class name(eg: SimpleCircle to SimpleCircle2) in the present file, then the error will be gone.

Comment: which files , show us the files ? also please check the stack overflow rules before posting question

Comment: The files I mentioned are .java files and these will be present in the folder where you are saving those files.For example I am presently working in Eclipse IDE and the folder's default name is "workspace".The path is C:\Users\<Users name>\workspace\<Project Name>\src\<Package name>\Test.java.In this folder if you have a java file having Class name same as the one you are using in the other java file you will encounter this error.